# CUDA/C++: Passing __device__ pointers in C++ code

Tags: pointers, cuda

I am developing a Windows 64-bit application that will manage concurrent execution of  different CUDA-algorithms on several GPUs.

My design requires a way of passing pointers to device memory
around c++ code. (E.g. remember them as members in my c++ objects).
I know that it is impossible to declare class members with `__device__` qualifiers.

However I couldn't find a definite answer whether assigning `__device__` pointer to a normal C pointer and then using the latter works. In other words: Is the following code valid?

```
__device__ float *ptr;
cudaMalloc(&ptr, size);
float *ptr2 = ptr
some_kernel<<<1,1>>>(ptr2);
```

For me it compiled and behaved correctly but I would like to know whether it is guaranteed to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that code isn't strictly valid. While it might work on the host side (more or less by accident), if you tried to dereference `ptr` directly from device code, you would find it would have an invalid value.

The correct way to do what your code implies would be like this:

```
__device__ float *ptr;

__global__ void some_kernel()
{
    float val = ptr[threadIdx.x];
    ....
}

float *ptr2;
cudaMalloc(&ptr2, size);
cudaMemcpyToSymbol("ptr", ptr2, sizeof(float *));

some_kernel<<<1,1>>>();
```

for CUDA 4.x or newer, change the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` to:

```
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(ptr, ptr2, sizeof(float *));
```

If the static device symbol `ptr` is really superfluous, you can just to something like this:

```
float *ptr2;
cudaMalloc(&ptr2, size);
some_kernel<<<1,1>>>(ptr2);
```

But I suspect that what you are probably looking for is something like the [thrust library `device_ptr` class](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1device__ptr.html), which is a nice abstraction wrapping the naked device pointer and makes it absolutely clear in code what is in device memory and what is in host memory.